# SEP-24 hosted deposit/withdraw transaction in Demo Wallet struck for long

Tags: horizon, testnet

Its more than a week now. We are facing issue with SEP-24 hosted deposit/withdraw transaction in Demo Wallet (TESTNET). https://demo-wallet.stellar.org/ All the transactions are struck with status: "waiting on the user to transfer funds" and the transaction getting failed after a long while. Is there any network issue/downtime? Kindly anybody suggest/advise Please?